# WiX gives component duplicate GUID error message when using star

Tags: wix, windows-installer, components, guid

Either there's something I don't understand about WiX or the single greatest coincidence in history is happening over-and-over-and-over.

I have a `<Component/>` element.  In this component I assign the GUID as an asterisk..... like ya do.

```
            <Component Id="Component_PowershellDLL"
                   Guid="*">
                   <File Source="$(var.MyProject.ProjectDir)System.Management.Automation.dll"/>
            </Component>
```

(I know I should use Nuget to access this DLL, but that's another story...)

When I compile, I get this error message:

> Component/@Id='Component_PowershellDLL' has a @Guid value'{guid-here}' that duplicates another component in this package.

The DLL in the component *is* used elsewhere in the project, but the only place that it lives is in the "MyProject" folder (hence, the `(var.MyProject.ProjectDir)`).

I *don't* get the error when I get rid of the star and just put in a regular old Guid.

Can anyone shed some light on this?  I was under the impression that when a star is used, it simply generates a new Guid.  So how can the Guid that it's generating be somewhere else in the project?

---

I see.  I *do* keep the DLL that the component installs in the same solution (`MyProject` in the example shown).

So, yes, the DLL that is referenced in the Component via a macros lives in the Visual Studio solution.

I suppose if they had different GUIDs (the DLL that lives in another project and the GUID that I put in the component that installs said DLL), then Windows Installer would have two GUIDs for the same... thing.

Thanks, y'all.  You guys are a true help in my foray into the world of Windows Installer.

@PhileDW I have your book sitting right beside me, but I haven't had time to really get into it yet.

Comment: If you got a useful answer, you should accept it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: In my case, this seemed to be caused by a long File/@Source paths (or perhaps a directory name with a period in it?)  Wix is supposed to generate the GUID based upon the filename portion of Source="...", but my guess is that it was mis-parsing the source path, and generating based upon a portion of the path that was the same for all files...

Answer (score 7):

WiX generates guids based on the path to the file, not completely randomly. The most likely explanation is that you've got that identical path somewhere else in your setup.

Comment: To add a bit more context for Bob, it deterministically generates a GUID so that component reference rules are followed and upgrades will continue to work properly. If it just made a completely new random GUID every build, there would be no way for Windows Installer to keep track of same components.